# renaming keys / values in objects dynamically

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, properties, key-value

I'm trying to put the values from the 'allValues' array inside the existing keys in the memory object, but instead they are just being added to the object after the existing keys, and they're keys are the index number. How can insert the values in the existing keys instead?

```
    const memories = {
        email: '',
        date: '',
        relation: '',
        tips: '',
        location: '',

    };

    const backend = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const allInputs = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('input'));
        const allValues = allInputs.map(input => input.value);
      
        for (const [index, value] of allValues.entries(){
            memories[index] = value;
        }
        console.log(memories);
    };
```

Comment: The title and the text are conflicting. The title says that you want to rename keys, the text says you want to replace values, which one is correct?

Answer (score 0):

You're retrieving the input values as an array, so you don't have any information about the names of the form fields.

You probably want something like:

```
const allInputs = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('input'));
const allValues = allInputs.map(({name, value}) => ({name, value}));
  
for (const {name, value} of allValues) {
    memories[name] = value;
}
```

---

**Complete snippet:**

```js
const memories = {
    email: '',
    date: '',
    relation: '',
    tips: '',
    location: '',

};

const allInputs = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('input'));
const allValues = allInputs.map(({name, value}) => ({name, value}));
  
for (const {name, value} of allValues) {
    memories[name] = value;
}

console.log(memories);
```

```html
<input name="email" value="test@example.com">
<input name="location" value="World">
```

Answer (score 0):

See working example at [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-oskar-cs5ts9?file=/src/index.js:0-293).

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Example</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <input type="text" name="email" value="a" />
    <input type="text" name="date" value="b" />
    <input type="text" name="relation" value="c" />
    <input type="text" name="tips" value="d" />
    <input type="text" name="location" value="e" />

    <button onclick="backend()">Submit</button>

    <script src="src/index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**index.js**

```
const memories = {
  email: "",
  date: "",
  relation: "",
  tips: "",
  location: ""
};

window.backend = () => {
  const allInputs = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("input"));

  allInputs.forEach((input) => {
    memories[input.name] = input.value;
  });

  console.log(memories);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the a `name` attribute for each input. The `document.querySelectorAll()` method returns a `NodeList`, and you can iterate it with `for..of`. Destructure the `name` and `value` in the the `for..of` loop, and update the object.

```js
const memories = {
  email: '',
  date: '',
  relation: '',
  tips: '',
  location: '',
};
  
for (const { name, value } of document.querySelectorAll('input')) {
  memories[name] = value;
}

console.log(memories);
```

```html
<input name="email" value="test@example.com" />
<input type="text" name="date" value="1.1.1970" />
<input type="text" name="relation" value="father" />
<input type="text" name="tips" value="tip" />
<input name="location" value="World" />
```

You can also use the `NodeList.forEach()` method instead of `for..of`:

```js
const memories = {
  email: '',
  date: '',
  relation: '',
  tips: '',
  location: '',
};

document.querySelectorAll('input')
  .forEach(({ name, value }) => {
    memories[name] = value;
  });
  
console.log(memories);
```

```html
<input name="email" value="test@example.com" />
<input type="text" name="date" value="1.1.1970" />
<input type="text" name="relation" value="father" />
<input type="text" name="tips" value="tip" />
<input name="location" value="World" />
```